# Creating a multidimensional list in python3 and assign values in a loop

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to create and fill in a multidimensional list in python 3.4 like this:

```
ret_array = []
```

then in a while list:

```
ret_array[k] = [track_name,t_num,disc_num,artist]
```

but this way I'm getting the error:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I know how many elements there will be but I'd prefer to do that more dynamically.

Any idea how I should do this the right way?

Comment: You can't assign to an index which doesn't exist yet, but you can just add to the list by using append. `ret_array.append([track_name,t_num,disc_num,artist])`

Comment: use button `{}` (instead of `<br>`) to correctly format code.

Comment: Your code example leaves much to be desired. Where's the `k` coming from? You might want to read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Many thanks, for the answer and the format hint:-)

Answer (score 0):

you can not assign a value to an index which doesn't exist but you can append it to the bottom of the list

```
ret_array.append([track_name,t_num,disc_num,artist])
```

or if you want to insert your element in a specific index you can use the insert function

```
ret_array.insert(k,[track_name,t_num,disc_num,artist])
```

you can also use dictionary like this

```
ret_array = {}
ret_array[k] = [track_name,t_num,disc_num,artist]
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! So, I can use also an index  to insert elements! good to know. I also will play around with the dictionary method. Could be even better...